# Should I replace this line in AGPL-3.0?

Tags: license-notice, agpl-3.0

In [AGPL 3.0](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html), on line 632, I see this:

> <one line to give the program's name and a brief idea of what it does.>
> Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>

I'm creating a software with this license, so I created a `LICENSE` file with the whole content of the license. Should I replace this line? Or is it the responsibility of the "new programs" creator?

> If you develop a new program, and you want it to be of the greatest possible use to the public, the best way to achieve this is to make it free software which everyone can redistribute and change under these terms.
>
> To do so, attach the following notices to the program. It is safest to attach them to the start of each source file to most effectively state the exclusion of warranty; and each file should have at least the "copyright" line and a pointer to where the full notice is found.

Comment: Are you asking if you should replace '<year>' and '<name of author>'  with the actual year and your actual name?

Comment: The placeholders in the LICENSE file itself should be retained; those placeholders are there for others which read the LICENSE and want to adopt the same license. However the placeholders which you put in your own files that have your own copyright should be filled in with your actual name. The notice is to show that you own the copyright to those and you are licensing them in a particular way.

Comment: @Brandin Ok thanks! You can post your second comment as an answer!

Comment: @Brandin: *Ping!* … Your comment would be a great answer and should be posted as one instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoting @Brandin](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6901/should-i-replace-this-line-in-agpl-3-0/6929#comment16969_6901):

> The placeholders in the `LICENSE` file itself should be retained; those placeholders are there for others which read the `LICENSE` and want to adopt the same license.
>
> However the placeholders which you put in your own files that have your own copyright should be filled in with your actual name. The notice is to show that you own the copyright to those and you are licensing them in a particular way.